# Liouville numbers with some "special" convergents

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, number-fields, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Recall that a real number $\ell$ is called a Liouville number, if there exists an infinite sequence of rational numbers $(p_n/q_n)_n$ for which
$$
0<\left|\ell-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\dfrac{1}{q_n^n},\ \forall n\geq 1.
$$

There are some results of the approximants $(p_n/q_n)$ of a Liouville number.

However, I am interested in proving (or disproving) the existence of a Liouville number, as defined before, but with the extra requirement that
$$
\deg\left(\left(\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right)^{p_n/q_n}\right)=o(n)
$$
as $n\to \infty$, i.e., the degree of the algebraic number $(p_n/q_n)^{p_n/q_n}$ is $o(n)$ (small 'o').

Someone could please give me some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $q_n$ distinct?

Comment: @LeechLattice Yes, $q_n$ tends to infinity as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Are the fractions $p_n/q_n$ distinct?